# Insert variable name into a function in R

Tags: r, survey

I'm trying to construct a function that calculate some variances using the survey package. The problem is that I need to insert the name of the variable (not the values of the variables) into a specific function (svyby)

Is something like this:

```
myfun=function(variable) {
svyby(~variable,~subpop,design,svymean)
}

myfun(P16)
```

It gives me error. I also tried with

```
*base[,variable]*
```

instead of

```
*variable*
```

the problem here that `base[,variable]` gives me the vector with the values of the variable, but I need the name of the variable to be read in the design object. What I mean is, I need that the function insert the name like this

```
svyby(~P16,~subpop,design,svymean)
```

I will appreciate any help, thank you in advance,
Gonzalo

Answer (score 4):

Looks like it needs a formula. You can paste a `"~"` to a string and use `as.formula`, like this:

```
myfun = function(variable) {
    svyby(as.formula(paste("~", variable)),
          ~subpop, design, svymean)
}
```

And then call is like this: `myfun("P16")`. Note that you will need to use a quoted column name because you are treating it like a string.

Alternatively, you could have your function take a formula:

```
myfun2 = function(formula) {
    svyby(formula,
          ~subpop, design, svymean)
}
```

And call it like this: `myfun2(~P16)`.